# ¿Como agregar un otro polígono a ejemplo Simple Polygon de Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-v3

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hoy me surgió el problema de como agregar un nuevo polígono al ejemplo Simple Polygon de google maps, necesito hacer un mapa de calor utilizando polígonos pero no se como se agregan, en el ejemplo Data Layer Poligon ya lo hice pero en ese ejemplo no muestra como "pintarlos" por así decirlos o si se pudiera con Data layer Poligon me seria de gran ayuda

Comment: Y de dónde obtendrías el color correspondiente a cada polígono? En tu origen de datos supongo que viene la geometría más alguna propiedad que determinará el color?

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo con [Data Layer: Styling](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-data-style?hl=es-419) y con la [documentación del objeto Data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=es-419#Data), podrás agregar el mismo estilo para todos los polígonos que agregues.

```
 map.data.setStyle({
      fillColor: 'green',
      strokeWeight: 1
    });
```

Si quieres estilo para cada polígono, deberás crear cada polígono por separado con su propio estilo y agregar cada uno al mapa

Comment: Hola Freddy eso ya lo hice pero me muestar el mismo estilo de uno en los dos en el color y la ventana de informacion

Comment: Así es. El método setStyle sólo admite un sólo objeto para estilizar todos los polígonos que hagas. De modo que lo que puedes hacer no usar Data Layer, y mejor crear tus polígonos cada uno por separado. Y creas un objeto para cada estilo ( por ejemplo, uno azul y otro rojo ) y le aplicas el objeto rojo a todos los de calor y el mismo objeto azul a todos los polígonos de frío.

Comment: pero la idea es que fueran mostrados en un solo poligono para que se viera pero si nho se puede tenre que buscar una forma de hacerlo porque ya tengo los poligonos que necesito pero me falta pintarlos y eso es loo que no puedo hacer

Comment: Veo que tienes un ">" al final de ambos strokeColor. Si los quitas cambia algo?

Comment: no amigo solo que hacia el cambio de color con un swich en php pero no le quite los ">" al cerrar la etiqueta de php

Answer (score 0):

[![Cuando lo hago se aplica el mismo estilo en los dos, puebla es el poligono mas pequeño y Puebla es el mas grande bueno
 te dejo la captura del codigo para que se aprecie mejor lo que quiero es poder hacer varios poligonos y poder cambiarles el color[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

[image: imagen con codigo nuevo]
No se si sea asi como se hace amigo la verdad no me sale un estilo para cada uno mira en la parte de var puebla (poligono pequeño) y var Puebla (poligono grande) desde ahi cargo las cooredendas de cada uno pero puedo hacer lo mismo como en  data poligon

Comment: no amigo solo que hacia el cambio de color con un swich en php pero no le quite los ">" al cerrar la etiqueta de php